# Accessing value of indirectly related models

Tags: php, yii

I am displaying a CGridView below CDetailView on view.php page for Company model. I have problem in displaying values in CGridView using company details. The company model has an array of CompanyAddresses which is used as CArrayDataProvider for CGridView.

```
      $config = array();
      $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($rawData=$model->companyAddresses,$config);
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider
    , 'columns'=>array(
                    //'id',
                    array('header'=>'SN.',
                    //'value'=>'++$row',  // may nt work with pagination but the below does work
                    'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',
                    ),
                     'address',
                        array(
                            'name'=>'Tehsil',
                            //'value'=> Utility::getTehsilName(Tehsil::model()->findByPk('tehsil_id')),
                            'value'=> Utility::getTehsilName($this->loadModel('tehsil_id')),
                            //'value'=> Tehsil::model()->findByAttributes( array('id' => 'tehsil_id' ) )->name,
                            ),
                        array(
                            'name'=>'address_tag_id',  
                                      'value'=>AddressTag::model()->findByPk('address_tag_id'),
                            ),

                    )

        ));
```

I am not able to fetch Tehsil_Name from Tehsil Table which has its ID inside CompanyAddress table.

Comment: I have written getTehsilName($tehsilID) method in a Utility.php class, placed inside protected/components. I am unable to pass tehsil_id to this function. I have tried various combinations for parameter passinng but in vain.

Comment: Where is `tehsil_id` obtained from?

Comment: Tehsil_id is obtained from companyAddress array elements, this array is part of Company model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using value attribute is wrong, check this:

```
'value'=>function($data){
     return Utility::getTehsilName($data->tehsil_id);
 },
```

Comment: your solution will load tehsil_id for Company Table where as I want CompanyAddress table's tehsil_id. The hierarchy is Company has CompanyAddresses has tehsil_id i.e. Company->CompanyAddress->Tehsil

Comment: I edited answer, your table structure is not clear for me, i just showing how can you use value field

Comment: Perfect. It worked with slight changes:

        'value'=>function($data){
           return Utility::getTehsilName($data->tehsil_id);
          },

Answer (score 0):

`value` is a php expression that is evaluated to produce the contents of the gridview cell as below

```
'value' => 'Utility::getTehsilName($this->grid->controller->loadModel($data->tehsil_id))'
```

If you had used [relation chaining](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/285/accessing-data-in-a-join-table-with-the-related-models/) to solve this your expression would have been simplified to say:

```
'value' => '$data->model1->tehsil->name'
```

where `model1` is the middle relation.